# Word Как вывести данные из VBA, в документ ворд

Tags: vba

Как вывести элементы данного массива в документ ворд?

```vb
Sub Задание2()
    Dim i, n As Integer
    Dim arr(1 To 1000) As Long
    n = InputBox("Введите число, не меньше 1")

    For i = 1 To n
        Randomize
        arr(i) = Int((n * 3 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Вставить в конец документа:

```
For i = 1 To n
  ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:=arr(i) & " "
Next
```